# Shopify "New Order Notification" Email Template

Tags: email, shopify

I want another item above Total that displays the total quantity.
Any ideas on how to do this with Liquid and have it work within the Shopify Email Template?

Here's my current snippet:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">  {% for line in line_items %} <li>  {{ line.quantity }}x
{{   line.title }} for {{ line.price | money }} each </li> {% endfor %} 
<li><br><b>Total: </b>{{ total_price | money }}</li>
</ul>
```

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `{{ item_count }}`. See the [Shopify docs here](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/notifications/email-variables#order-fulfillment) for a list of the order variables you have access to in email templates:

> **item_count:** A sum of all the items' quantities.